# Google Cloud Storage: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage

Up until yesterday, all of our environments were able to use the Java API for saving and retrieving files to Google Cloud Storage.

Google internet authority certificate has been added to our keystore, and a P12 Certificate has been generated to access the storage.

This has all been working fine, in our Dev and Sys environments and has all of a sudden started reporting the following error!

Has anyone any knowledge of certificate changes or anything else that may have started this issue to suddenly start happening?

Comment: I can't help myself, but as general guidance, post a snippet of the code causing the error, and any other details that might help diagnose. Also the stacktrace.

Comment: Seconding Andrew - this question needs more details. What code produced that error message? What keystore are you referring to? How do you connect to Google Cloud Storage? Code snippets? Stack traces?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of update, this issue was caused by a combination of google updating their certificates to SHA256 (but not all) and Oracle Weblogic 10.3.6 (using jdk 1.6) having an issue with the fact that these aren't update properly (message is Bac record mac).  Oracle have suggested upgrading the jdk, google have suggested adding their root certificates.  Both of these things I will try, and I'll update.  I am using a p12 certificate created for authentication, and using the Java/JSON implementation.  PS. Worked a dream, before all this certificate crap!

Comment: PS. The question wasn't about the code working or not, as my code had been in production for several weeks before it stopped working, it was more about 'What have google done now, without notifying users!  As it turned out, on the day I initially had the problem, google cloud storage was unavailable for a couple of hours, but finding this wasn't easy!  This seemed to be when the certificates were updated too!